# How do I prevent <c-u> from deleting the line in completefunc in vim

Tags: vim

I have a completefunc that returns "Some string 1 ", "Some string 2" but every time the completion menu comes up it deletes all of my current line. I loose my previous text unless I go back to the original. I tried remapping   to do nothing and it continues to delete my line. I would like it to behave more like when you want to complete a file name with .

I don't want it to do this.
[image]

I want it to do this.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you have a NUL byte after `Some string 1^@`? I suspect it's vims way to internally store a newline? But why is it there?

Comment: @andlrc Good question. That's a new line that I added to 'word' key but even when I add a normal string it still does the same thing, it dose not delete what it is behind but nor dose it display it. I found a work around though by just including the current line to 'word'. It's not a solution, more of a HACK. I guess completion just works like that. I don't know? It does not do that for ctrl-xctrl-s when you try to correct a spelling but then again that's just one word not an entire sentence. Who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> being interpreted as a "clear to the start of line" command, but instead with your `'completefunc'` not implementing the "findstart" part appropriately.

See [`:help complete-functions`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#complete-functions):

> On the first invocation the arguments are:
>
> - `a:findstart`:  1
> - `a:base`:  empty
>
> The function must return the column where the completion starts.  It must be a number between zero and the cursor column `col('.')`.  This involves looking at the characters just before the cursor and including those characters that could be part of the completed item.  The text between this column and the
> cursor column will be replaced with the matches.

If your function is not implementing this part, it's likely Vim is getting "0", which it's taking to mean the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem added this to fix it ```return match(getline('.'), '\v\w+\s*$')``` . Happy Holidays ! :)

Comment: Glad this fixed it! Happy Holidays to you as well! :-D